# Error when using createDataPartition in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to follow a guide to learn how to use machine learning in R.
I've used a sample data set online which probably has missing values.

This is what I am using to split the data:

```
validation_index <- createDataPartition(Test$Quantity, p=0.80, list=FALSE, times = 1, "na.rm=TRUE")
```

I receive this error:

> Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = groups)) :     missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

I have tried to include

```
na.rm=TRUE
```

in my line of code but it does not solve the problem with the error.

I've also tried using

```
complete.cases(Test)
```

for missing values but it does not seem to help.

I'm fairly new to R and looked around a lot to find the answer but could not so far but perhaps I am not understanding it correctly. Do you know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by converting the response (dependent) variable from an integer to a factor, e.g.

```
Test$Quantity <- as.factor(Test$Quantity)
```

before attempting the partition.